# GDB 7.5 (OS X): Can't access source from library functions

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, gdb

gdb newbie here, so I hope I haven't overlooked something glaringly obvious… (and if I did, maybe a kind soul could point it out anyway? ;)

I'm debugging a GCC C++ application under OS X Lion. As it's quite heavy on STL, I'd really like to use a GDB version with python support (i.e. >=v7) for pretty printing of containers. My application is split up into a backend library (.dylib) that does all the heavy lifting, and a very simple frontend application. All of the sources and binaries are below a common source path, and everything has been compiled with debugging symbols (I tried both -g and -ggdb).

Using the GDB version in XCode (which identifies as "GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1820)"), displaying the source lines of frames in a backtrace works as expected out of the box, no matter whether the respective call happens in the frontend app or the backend library:

(gdb) f 12

#12 0x000000010002ddc5 in FL3D::Resource::createMesh_ (this=0x7fff5fbff7c8, fl3d=@0x7fff5fbff1f8, id=) at /Development/workspace/fl3d/libfl3d/resource.cpp:234

234             std::vector& t = textureIndices_.at(i);

(gdb)

So far so good. GDB 7.5 and 7.4.1, on the other hand, refuse to give me any source lines from the library:

(gdb) f 12

#12 0x000000010002ddc5 in FL3D::Resource::createMesh_(FL3D::FL3DParser&, std::string) ()
   from /Development/workspace/fl3d/libfl3d/build/libfl3d.dylib

(gdb)

I'm really confused by the different responses given – gdb6 prints the correct path to the source file and the correct line, while gdb7 gets the function prototype right (supposedly read from the debugging symbols of the .dylib?), but doesn't seem to know anything about the source. Interestingly, though, it DOES show the corresponding source line for calls in the frontend's main() function!

I've already tried manually setting the path to the library's source files with "dir libfl3d", but that doesn't change anything. I also notice that gdb6 says "Reading symbols for shared libraries" a few times when I run the application and gdb7 doesn't – but the symbols don't seem to be the problem, as they seem to be resolved correctly by both versions?

I'm at my wit's end here. Any pointers?

Comment: If you'd like a debugger with python support Apple provides [LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org/) with Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple gdb is displaying the debug information because it knows how to find & parse DWARF on this platform.  The gdb version 7 that you're showing is a gdb that doesn't know how to find the DWARF debug information on a Mac OS X system -- that output that you're showing above is what no-debug-info looks like.  My guess is that the FSF gdb version 7 support for Mac OS X has not seen a lot of attention, I would be hesitant to recommend using it on this platform.

As *bames53* notes, you're far better off using LLDB on Mac OS X at this point.  It is the debugger that all of the support work is going in to and Objective-C / C++ container support is rapidly being added to LLDB but not gdb.  The gdb provided by Apple is on an end-of-life path and all users will be switched over to LLDB in the future.

Give lldb a try.  It's a little different but it's quite good.  There is a cheat sheet that a lot of people find useful in the beginning, it shows gdb and lldb command equivalences.  http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html